I am having a Post request "HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name." in scrapy while using Scrapeops proxies
my post request is working fine without scrapeops proxies but client said not to disable proxies.My request requires both cookies and headers along with payload data to get json response, here are my headers and cookies:
cookies = {
            'tg_session_25008_5012': '^TAmfhlbvqGGm3Vo9KBWxZJqolgCqcCoXPEO9qDwlTkJyhEFcx7zrQeseu8KOyFsEjx3D3GAbMVOcU7Agx7LOq90ub7wGGK354CKkKngCOH4=',
            'tg_session': '^TAmfhlbvqGGm3Vo9KBWxZJqolgCqcCoXPEO9qDwlTkJyhEFcx7zrQeseu8KOyFsEjx3D3GAbMVOcU7Agx7LOq90ub7wGGK354CKkKngCOH4=',
            'tg_rft': '^mHOwVU4ei7NrQmF6n2llJb/gAewiggqW8DkdZR4sm9lKjwoWo3Nf4D4dN8aqigFzzljy446oEvDpcUWUpgMSEPcZ3tSH90ojDHue1sa6zgo=',
            'tg_rft_mvc': '1RJwHo4bG8T09Qfvi1Y9tZfyUGF-1x_sH9RnYG840X_fXpW418Lv--2T9duP2H-mrx7OFxrxOIzX3CJ5Zd8NJgIQ0fV_7vn-LEaw4mFgapF1QEHM4C7gByEUjlYhIR55MY_IJA2',
            'geo-country': 'PK',
            'sat_track': 'true',
            's_lv_s': 'First%20Visit',
            'AMCVS_73FAC51D54C72AE50A4C98BC%40AdobeOrg': '1',
            's_ecid': 'MCMID%7C75522721953618165144521412867917598680',
            's_visit': '1',
            's_mtouch': 'Internal',
            's_cc': 'true',
            'aam_uuid': '75493351460292711974518490112521156743',
            'AAMSID': 'AAM%3D21740122%3A21739909',
            'AMCV_73FAC51D54C72AE50A4C98BC%40AdobeOrg': '770003774%7CMCIDTS%7C19984%7CMCMID%7C75522721953618165144521412867917598680%7CMCAAMLH-1727203260%7C3%7CMCAAMB-1727203260%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1726605660s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.5.0%7CMCCIDH%7C-1236019896',
            's_ppn': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html',
            's_gpv_url2': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers.html',
            's_gpv_channel': 'global%3Acareers%3Ameet%20us%3Aresponsive_content',
            's_gpv_url': 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html',
            's_nr': '1726598461275-New',
            's_lv': '1726598461275',
            's_ppvl': 'https%253A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html%2C53%2C5%2C1741%2C1366%2C641%2C1366%2C768%2C1%2CP',
            'scrollTracking': 'true',
            's_ht': '1726598485291',
            's_hc': '1%7C0%7C1%7C0%7C2',
            's_ppv': 'https%253A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html%2C100%2C53%2C3295%2C1366%2C641%2C1366%2C768%2C1%2CP',
            's_sq': 'ubs-loglive%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ubs.com%25252Fglobal%25252Fen%25252Fcareers%25252Fmeet-us.html%2526link%253DOK%2526region%253Ddoc%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ubs.com%25252Fglobal%25252Fen%25252Fcareers%25252Fmeet-us.html%2526oid%253DOK%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT',
            'ubs_cookie_settings_2.0.4': '0-4-3-2-1',
            'tg_rft': '^mHOwVU4ei7NrQmF6n2llJb/gAewiggqW8DkdZR4sm9lKjwoWo3Nf4D4dN8aqigFzzljy446oEvDpcUWUpgMSEPcZ3tSH90ojDHue1sa6zgo=',
        }

        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            # 'Cookie': 'tg_session_25008_5012=^TAmfhlbvqGGm3Vo9KBWxZJqolgCqcCoXPEO9qDwlTkJyhEFcx7zrQeseu8KOyFsEjx3D3GAbMVOcU7Agx7LOq90ub7wGGK354CKkKngCOH4=; tg_session=^TAmfhlbvqGGm3Vo9KBWxZJqolgCqcCoXPEO9qDwlTkJyhEFcx7zrQeseu8KOyFsEjx3D3GAbMVOcU7Agx7LOq90ub7wGGK354CKkKngCOH4=; tg_rft=^mHOwVU4ei7NrQmF6n2llJb/gAewiggqW8DkdZR4sm9lKjwoWo3Nf4D4dN8aqigFzzljy446oEvDpcUWUpgMSEPcZ3tSH90ojDHue1sa6zgo=; tg_rft_mvc=1RJwHo4bG8T09Qfvi1Y9tZfyUGF-1x_sH9RnYG840X_fXpW418Lv--2T9duP2H-mrx7OFxrxOIzX3CJ5Zd8NJgIQ0fV_7vn-LEaw4mFgapF1QEHM4C7gByEUjlYhIR55MY_IJA2; geo-country=PK; sat_track=true; s_lv_s=First%20Visit; AMCVS_73FAC51D54C72AE50A4C98BC%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C75522721953618165144521412867917598680; s_visit=1; s_mtouch=Internal; s_cc=true; aam_uuid=75493351460292711974518490112521156743; AAMSID=AAM%3D21740122%3A21739909; AMCV_73FAC51D54C72AE50A4C98BC%40AdobeOrg=770003774%7CMCIDTS%7C19984%7CMCMID%7C75522721953618165144521412867917598680%7CMCAAMLH-1727203260%7C3%7CMCAAMB-1727203260%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1726605660s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.5.0%7CMCCIDH%7C-1236019896; s_ppn=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html; s_gpv_url2=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers.html; s_gpv_channel=global%3Acareers%3Ameet%20us%3Aresponsive_content; s_gpv_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html; s_nr=1726598461275-New; s_lv=1726598461275; s_ppvl=https%253A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html%2C53%2C5%2C1741%2C1366%2C641%2C1366%2C768%2C1%2CP; scrollTracking=true; s_ht=1726598485291; s_hc=1%7C0%7C1%7C0%7C2; s_ppv=https%253A%2F%2Fwww.ubs.com%2Fglobal%2Fen%2Fcareers%2Fmeet-us.html%2C100%2C53%2C3295%2C1366%2C641%2C1366%2C768%2C1%2CP; s_sq=ubs-loglive%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ubs.com%25252Fglobal%25252Fen%25252Fcareers%25252Fmeet-us.html%2526link%253DOK%2526region%253Ddoc%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ubs.com%25252Fglobal%25252Fen%25252Fcareers%25252Fmeet-us.html%2526oid%253DOK%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT; ubs_cookie_settings_2.0.4=0-4-3-2-1; tg_rft=^mHOwVU4ei7NrQmF6n2llJb/gAewiggqW8DkdZR4sm9lKjwoWo3Nf4D4dN8aqigFzzljy446oEvDpcUWUpgMSEPcZ3tSH90ojDHue1sa6zgo=',
            'Origin': 'https://jobs.ubs.com',
            'RFT': 'XggmEZZl_onTMvzo1OXHKL7GGQ494onDiAt8VQis0jk4M6IhNbtF_PM1prnkjQv_0ikrKd7kp9t4lsz1TzU5Dd1IIhsKZgw0UBz1pkh50ysHchN16nFJlH5VI1wAbowucA_xcQ2',
            'Referer': 'https://jobs.ubs.com/TGnewUI/Search/home/HomeWithPreLoad?partnerid=25008&siteid=5012&PageType=searchResults&SearchType=linkquery&LinkID=6015',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        }

here is my request:
yield scrapy.Request(url, method='POST', callback=self.parse_detail, body=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, cookies=cookies, meta={'sops_keep_headers': True, })

here is the response when i use proxies:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

simply when i disable the proxies and send request it works proper and json response i received but when i use scrapeops proxies it it give Bad Request
